# Movie About Body Snatchers In Old Western Town

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, shape-shifter

I watched this movie back around 2010 I would say, but the video quality looked like it was made in the 80's.

There's a family driving through the desert at night, a mom and dad plus a brother and sister. They get off the highway and stop in this old abandoned looking town for gas or maybe just a rest stop presumably.

The sequences of the events that happen next are a blur but here's what I recall. The kids wait in the car while the parents go look around, and the town is pretty empty except for a few strange behaving people. The kids get out of the car after waiting for a long time and eventually end up in a building, potentially a basement? They find their parents covered in either goo or some cocoon. Then they run into their parents, and conclude that it's creatures pretending to be their parents.

At some point they attack one of the creatures, I think they hit him with an axe and green blood oozes everywhere. Big memory gap, but I'm pretty sure they free their parents and drive away. Not positive but at the end I think it shows a brief scene where the parents in the car are still creatures in disguise.

Comment: Could you possibly decribe the car and the family in detail? How old were the kids? Hair color?

Comment: I belive they were driving a light brown car typical for the 80s, a station wagon perhaps. The kids looked to be around 12 years old, pretty sure one of them had glasses. Not sure on the hair color.